How to get sshd.service to start after network-online.target on raspbian 12 (bookworm)?
Things I've tried:

Changing After=network.target to After=network-online.target via systemctl edit --full sshd.service
Creating file /etc/systemd/system/sshd.service.d/network-online.conf with contents of

[Unit]
After=network-online.target


Changing After=network.target to After=network-online.target and adding Wants=network-online.target via systemctl edit --full sshd.service

Each time sshd.service fails to bind to it's IP address, there was one difference with the third attempt where when attempting to ssh to the raspberry pi instead of the usual 'connection refused' it returned instead with 'kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer'
My goal here is for my raspberry pi to start the sshd.service successfully at boot.
I am using a raspberry pi 1 b+ with raspbian 12 bookworm with NetworkManager.
@grawity I would prefer it to bind to an individual address and haven't had an issue before with it, here is the output of that command:
$ sudo systemctl list-dependencies --after network-online.target
network-online.target
● ├─networking.service
● ├─NetworkManager-wait-online.service
× ├─systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
● └─network.target
●   ├─ifupdown-pre.service
●   ├─networking.service
●   ├─NetworkManager.service
●   ├─systemd-networkd.service
●   ├─wpa_supplicant.service
●   └─network-pre.target
●     └─ufw.service

@Jaromanda X I need to be able to configure sshd_config for key authentication, I don't understand why raspi-config should be avoided when enabling ssh but i'll try reinstalling with it enabled in the imager and edit my post later


does it have to specifically bind to individual addresses? 2) does the .target actually have anything in it per 'systemctl list-dependencies --after...'?


@grawity
network-online.target
● ├─networking.service
● ├─NetworkManager-wait-online.service
× ├─systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
● └─network.target
●   ├─ifupdown-pre.service
●   ├─networking.service
●   ├─NetworkManager.service
●   ├─systemd-networkd.service
●   ├─wpa_supplicant.service
●   └─network-pre.target
●     └─ufw.service


@phenivol you realise that comment is particularly useless?

My goal here is for my raspberry pi to start the sshd.service successfully at boot. it does on all my 16 raspberry pi's ranging from pi1B to pi4B, without changing a single configuration - what have you changed before attempting to fix it by fiddling with sshd?

@JaromandaX Was grawity not asking for the output of that command for network-online.target? I didn't mess with anything else, i installed raspbian with raspberry pi imager, i enabled ssh through raspi-config, then i set up sshd_config and ufw, i looked at the configs of others that are currently working fine on my desktop and laptop, ssh did not start at boot at any point, i've had to use systemctl to start it myself. Even after being enabled on my desktop and laptop they didn't start at boot without the 2nd solution in the original post

Was grawity not asking for the output of that command for network-online.target? ys, but it's not very readable  - you can add the info to the question, where it would be readable

I didn't mess with anything else, i installed raspbian with raspberry pi imager, i enabled ssh through raspi-config, then i set up sshd_config and ufw - you know what I do? I enable ssh in raspberry pi imager, I write the image, I DON'T muck with sshd_config and raspi-config, I dont install ufw  - that's 3 less things than you, and I have 16+ raspberry pi's that respond to SSH

network-online.target is triggered before NetworkManager.service starts up fully, sshd.service tries to bind to the IP and fails. The solution is to systemctl edit --full sshd.service and set the following:
[Unit]
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5

You will also want to remove RestartPreventExitStatus=255 if present.
This allows sshd.service to restart when it inevitably fails on start up without restarting too quickly.
